# interaction plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

The following code shows an interaction plot using the `effects` library:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt + hp:wt, data=mtcars)
library(effects)
plot(effect("hp:wt", model, list(wt=c(2.2,3.2,4.2))), multiline=TRUE)
```

[image]

I tried making the same model but holding `wt` at 2.2, but this model could not calculate the coefficient for `wt`:

```
mtcars$wt_2.2 <- 2.2
model2.2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + wt_2.2 + hp:wt, data=mtcars)
coef(model2.2)
```

How can I make the same plot using ggplot2?

Comment: https://github.com/ggobi/cranvas/wiki

Comment: What have you tried? As it stands, the question is in danger of being closed and tossed into the river.

Comment: I've added what I've tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tmp <- as.data.frame(effect("hp:wt", model, list(wt=c(2.2,3.2,4.2))))
ggplot(data=tmp, aes(x=hp, y=fit, colour=as.factor(wt))) +
       geom_line() +
       labs(colour="wt")
```

[image: plot]